# How to get path when I drop some folder in text field

Tags: java, swing

I use Java Swing, I have a text field where I can put some folder path by using jfile chooser but I want do this directly, drop this folder and get the path. If some code is given as an example it will helpful for me.

Please give some code example if possible because I do not understand this code which is given in this link [How can I use Drag-and-Drop in Swing to get file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path) and which is given in Sun Oracle site also. Please describe this code.  I am new to Java Swing.

Comment: Drag&Drop is your friend and a similiar question has been answered before: [How can I use Drag-and-Drop in Swing to get file path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path)

Comment: @ Andreas_D I see the similer post on this forum but it gives the total files list not folder path.am i right

Comment: You could check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669530/drag-and-drop-file-path-to-java-swing-jtextfield?lq=1)