# How to allow the java jTextPane accept dragging an external file?

Tags: swing, drag-and-drop, jtextpane

I googled about drag and drop example, but I only found that application drag and drop via the application internally, but I would like to drag and external file on the jTextPane... How can I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the Swing Drag and Drop support.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path).