# How to Drag and Drop my groupwise email directly to my java component?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I want to Drag and drop my groupwise email directly to my java panel.I can able to drag and drop my groupwise email after placing it on windows explorer(the mail becomes .eml file).

```
public synchronized void drop(final DropTargetDropEvent dtde)
{
try
{

Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();

}
```

While i try the above code ,there is no Dataflavors.
Plz So give me your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a list of absolute path of .eml files that has been dropped onto the swing component and then your code can get those files from that path for further operation.

You can implement `Transferable` into your own class that can be used to provide data for a transfer operation and extend `TransferHandler` class to define your own `DataFlavor`.

Comment: Hi Ashish, Thanks for your information,Could you plz elaborate it more,Because i have no much idea about these Transferable and TransferHandler

Comment: @Sweeten I am taking about - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/transferhandler.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html

Comment: see for more help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204580/swing-application-drag-drop-to-the-desktop-folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path

Comment: Hi, I need more support to implement.

Comment: Can anyone help me to implement this option.

Comment: What is the difference between  DropTargetDropEvent -->SourceAction -3 & 1073741827 ?