# java Drag and Drop - List doesn't take parametrs

Tags: java, swing, list, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a simple application, which use DnD to get file path. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path) practicly the same thing, which I would like to use. But I got an Error - typ List does not take parameters. When i try DnD just if it works, I get positive answer, but I don't know any other possibility, how to get file path. Here's code, which I use:

```
jTextField8.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
        public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent evt) {
            try {
                evt.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
                List<File> droppedFiles = (List<File>) evt.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                for (File file : droppeFiles) {
                    jTextArea1.append("Drag & Drop OK");
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: uhm...are you compiling against a JDK 5.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your imports.

You're probably using `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List<E>`. `java.awt.List` is a non-generic GUI component (i.e., it does not take type parameters), while `java.awt.List<E>` is a generic data structure.

If you're *intentionally* using `java.awt.List` for GUI, remember that it's deprecated (or at least abandoned) as part of original AWT; consider switching to `javax.swing.JList`.

If you *absolutely have to* use `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List<E>` in the same file:

```
java.awt.List myGuiList = new java.awt.List();
java.util.List<File> myFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
```