# How do I create an area were files dragged into it add the URI to a list?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, drag-and-drop, absolute-path

I am trying to create a program were the user drags a file into an area (currently a JTextArea, but can be another container) and it adds the absolute path of the file to an ArrayList.  I am having trouble figuring out how to implement drag and drop of files.

so far I have tried reading some similar questions but they aren't really helping me.
(also this is targeting windows but linux/mac support is an option as well)

Comment: So, you're using Swing?

Comment: And possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path

Comment: "asked May 1 '09 at 13:00" to the above and i did not see that one in my searches, ill read into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at oracles page about [DnD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html). Basically you can drag everything into your program, should it be a file directly from a native browser or the `JFileChooser`. What you are dragging is only the path to the file. So you only have to set your `JTextArea`to accept drops and define how it has to "interpret" the object that was being dropped.

Comment: already looked at the dnd section but didn't see anything about files, must have overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full blown [example](http://blog.christoffer.me/2011/01/drag-and-dropping-files-to-java-desktop.html).