# @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") not working with drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, suppress-warnings

I am using the following code that I found ([How can I use Drag-and-Drop in Swing to get file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path) from ABika) to do drag and drop:

```
final class FileDropHandler extends TransferHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        for (DataFlavor flavor : support.getDataFlavors()) {
            if (flavor.isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        if (!this.canImport(support))
            return false;

        List<File> files;
        try {
            files = (List<File>) support.getTransferable()
                    .getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
            // should never happen (or JDK is buggy)
            return false;
        }

        for (File file: files) {
            // do something...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The handler is then added to a component.

But the problem is that despite the "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")", I am getting an error:

> The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments < File>

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? It seems so straight-forward.
Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce. Maybe you have another class called List?

Comment: please add your imports. I assume the class `List` you have does not come from `java.util`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getTransferData` is supposed to return a `java.util.List` in this case but you are importing `java.awt.List`, either as a single-type import statement i.e. `import java.awt.List;` or as an import-on-demand statement i.e. `import java.awt.*;`. If you have the former, you need to change it to `java.util.List` and if you have the latter, you need to import every class from `java.awt` as a single-type import instead, or use a qualified `List` type name in the `importData` method, like `java.util.List<File>`.

Comment: That works great!
I could have saved the last 3 hours.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing the "unchecked" warning only works on generic types that undergo unchecked operations like a generic cast. It does not suppress an outright error like putting a generic argument on a non-generic type. You added a generic parameter to a non-generic type `List`. That's an error that cannot be suppressed.