# Drag and Drop Files - TransferHandler vs. DropTarget vs. FileDrop?

Tags: java, swing, file, drag-and-drop

So, in [How can I use Drag-and-Drop in Swing to get file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811248/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-in-swing-to-get-file-path), several different solutions are suggested: one pointing to the [`TransferHandler` tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/toplevel.html) (which doesn't actually explain how to drag and drop files, only explaining dragging JComponents, and then giving a demo with multiple moving parts and no explanation for files), one using `DropTarget` and `DropTargetDropEvent`, and one using an external library called `FileDrop`.  The fourth answer (thankfully) actually explained what `TransferHandler` is and how to implement it for files, but the question I have is:

**Which of these methods is best to use?**

I don't know about using the external library if there is native support, but the big thing I don't understand is `DropTarget`.

I've only previously seen `DropTarget` used in programs written in Java 7 and earlier, so I assumed that it was made obsolete by `TransferHandler`, but the solution in the linked question says that it should be used for Java 7 or *later*.  I'm very confused.

Thank you for your time, and I look forward to a response!

Answer (score 1):

imho there is no generally best method for drag&drop. For simple file drag&drop (e.g. files from the file explorer) I would use the `DropTargetListener`. `TransferHandle` is likely to be used for drag&drop between components or applications.

You need a `DropTarget` to define the type of drop operation (e.g. copy and/or move) and the `DropTargetListener`.

An example that you might know (somewhat messy):
[Drag&Drop Example on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597233/how-to-drag-and-drop-files-from-a-directory-in-java/13597635#13597635)

As an example I wrote a panel class that implements drag&drop via `DropTargetListener`. A derivation of this class which overrides `importFiles` can directly access a `List<File>`.

```
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DropTargetPanel extends JPanel implements DropTargetListener {
    private static final String NL = "\\r?\\n";
    private static final List<DataFlavor> supportedFlavors = 
        new ArrayList<>( List.of(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor, DataFlavor.stringFlavor) );

    public DropTargetPanel() {
        super();
        new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        if(supportedFlavors.contains(dtde.getCurrentDataFlavors()[0])) {
            dtde.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
        } else {
            dtde.rejectDrag();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        dragEnter(dtde);
    }

    @Override
    public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) { /* */ }

    @Override
    public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) { /* */ }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        // It looks like only the first flavor is guaranteed to work for me - so what
        DataFlavor df = dtde.getCurrentDataFlavors()[0];
        Transferable transferable = dtde.getTransferable();
        
        if(supportedFlavors.contains(df)) {
            dtde.acceptDrop(dtde.getDropAction());
            if(df.isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                try { importFiles((List<File>)transferable.getTransferData(df)); }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
            } else {
                try { importFiles(getFiles(((String)transferable.getTransferData(df)).split(NL))); } 
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
            }                
            dtde.dropComplete(true);
        }
        else dtde.rejectDrop();
    }

    // Creates a List<File> from a String Array
    private List<File> getFiles(String[] files){
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) result.add(new File(files[i]));
        return result;
    }

    // Override this to gain access for the list of files
    protected void importFiles(List<File> files) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi QuinncyJones, Can you explain your answer? What is your code showing?

Comment: Hi bsheps, I should have added an explanation right away. Thanks for the hint!